# Previous / Next button for a linklist - not working as expected

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm attempting to build a "Next / Previous" page navigation system for pages in a `linklist`.

The code below works as expected... except on the first and last page on the linklist. I want the "Previous" button to **not** show on the first page, and the "Next" button to **not** show on the last page.

On the first page, the "Previous" button shows, and points to the last page.

On the last page, the "Next" button shows, but points nowhere.

Where am I going wrong? The only thing I can think is that I'm not giving the variables the correct types (I'm relatively new to Liquid).

```
  {% comment %}
    Get the linklist being passed, and the size of the linklist.
  {% endcomment %}

  {% assign thislinklist = __page-navigation-arrows %}
  {% assign thislinklistSize = linklists[thislinklist].links | plus: 0 %}

  {% comment %}
    Finds the index of the current page in the linklist array, and saves it to compare to find previous and next pages.
  {% endcomment %}

  {% for link in linklists[thislinklist].links %}
    {% if page.handle == link.handle %}
      {% assign thisindex = forloop.index0 | plus: 0 %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% comment %}
    Saves details of the current page, and indexes of the previous and nex pages.
  {% endcomment %}

  {% assign thisname = page.title %}
  {% assign thislink = page.url %}

  {% assign thisindex = thisindex | plus: 0 %}
  {% assign previndex = thisindex | minus: 1 %}
  {% assign nextindex = thisindex | plus: 1 %}

  {% comment %}
    If it's not the last page in the linklist, save details of the next page. If not, assign a blank string (used later to hide the button).
  {% endcomment %}

  {% if previndex | plus: 0 > 0 %}
    {% assign prevname = linklists[thislinklist].links[previndex].title %}
    {% assign prevlink = linklists[thislinklist].links[previndex].url %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign prevname = '' %}
    {% assign prevlink = '' %}
  {% endif %}

  {% comment %}
    If it's not the first page in the linklist, save details of the previous page. If not, assign a blank string (used later to hide the button).
  {% endcomment %}

  {% if nextindex | plus: 0 < thislinklistSize | minus: 1 %}
    {% assign nextname = linklists[thislinklist].links[nextindex].title %}
    {% assign nextlink = linklists[thislinklist].links[nextindex].url %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign nextname = '' %}
    {% assign nextlink = '' %}
  {% endif %}


  {% comment %}
    Display the navigation.
  {% endcomment %}

  <div class="page-navigation-arrows">

    {% comment %} Hide "Previous" if it's the first page {% endcomment %}
    {% if prevlink != '' or blank %}
      <a class="page-navigation-arrows__prev page-navigation-arrows__arrow" href="{{ prevlink }}" title="{{ prevname }}">
        <img src="{{ 'page-navigation-prev.svg' | asset_url }}" alt="Previous Page">
      </a>
    {% endif %}

    {% comment %} Hide "Next" if it's the last page {% endcomment %}
    {% if nextlink != '' or blank %}
      <a class="page-navigation-arrows__next page-navigation-arrows__arrow" href="{{ nextlink }}" title="{{ nextname }}">
        <img src="{{ 'page-navigation-next.svg' | asset_url }}" alt="Next Page">
      </a>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No time to test this, but I will believe you that the code works.

But there a few things:

`{% if nextlink != '' or blank %}`

This is not a valid `if` condition. It should be:

`{% if nextlink != '' or nextlink == blank %}`

---

This is not a valid if statement as well:

`{% if previndex | plus: 0 > 0 %}`

it always returns `true`. It should become:

```
{% assign previndex = previndex | plus: 0 %}
{% if previndex > 0 %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Once you fix these issues it should be working properly.

Comment: `{% if nextlink != '' or nextlink == blank %}` is also redundant - An empty string matches the keyword `blank`, so this statement will always evaluate as true.  It might be more in line with the intent to simply use `{% if nextlink != blank %}...{% endif %}` (or `{% unless nextlink == blank %}...{% endunless %}` if you prefer)

Comment: @DaveB - Thanks, I'm used to Javascript and assumed `blank` is similar to JavaScript's `null`. In Javascript, `null != ""` is `false`.

Comment: @drip, thanks for the solution. I'm not yet used to how liquid's operators work and the filters are mighty confusing to me who is coming to Javascript, especially using `| plus: 0` to force the type as a number instead of explicitly typing it.

Comment: Aye - `blank` is a very handy keyword in Liquid - it matches null/nil, false, '' and empty-object.  Of those, only null/nil and false are considered false-y for the purposes of an `if` or `unless` statement

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to achieve this:

{% unless forloop.first %}
    Your code for previous link
  {% endunless %}

{% unless forloop.last %}
    Your code for next link
  {% endunless %}

Comment: Thanks for that, although this would render as many prev/next arrows as there are `(links in the list - 1)`.

The loop would iterate through each link, check if it's the first or last, and print an arrow if it isn't.

Comment: As you open the loop on each page and as I see no {% break %} in your loop your code already check each link. By the way your code is really long and not optimized and you could write it simplier and actually use a break in your loop.

Comment: Thanks, Alice. I'm not used to Liquid's syntax and didn't know that there was actually a break keyword you can use.